# gulp failed on Jenkins, but succeed on my VM

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, webpack, gulp-sass

I am pretty new to npm and nodejs. what does the output mean? How to debug?

some version info:

```
10:29:33 + echo ==========================+
10:29:33 ==========================+
10:29:33 + which node
10:29:33 /usr/bin/node
10:29:33 + echo ==========================+
10:29:33 ==========================+
10:29:33 + /usr/local/n/versions/node/5.5.0/bin/node --version
10:29:33 v5.5.0
10:29:33 + echo ==========================+
10:29:33 ==========================+
10:29:33 + node -v
10:29:33 v0.10.37
10:29:33 + echo ==========================+
10:29:33 ==========================+
10:29:33 + /usr/local/n/versions/node/5.5.0/bin/npm --version
10:29:33 3.3.12
10:29:33 + echo ==========================+
10:29:33 ==========================+
```

**...**

error output:

```
10:30:42 + /usr/local/n/versions/node/5.5.0/bin/npm run build
10:30:43 
10:30:43 > myproject@1.0.0 build /tmp/3791.work
10:30:43 > gulp && webpack
10:30:43 
10:30:43 
10:30:43 /tmp/3791.work/gulpfile.js:30
10:30:43 gulp.task( 'sass', () => {
10:30:43                     ^
10:30:43 SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
10:30:43     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
10:30:43     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
10:30:43     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
10:30:43     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
10:30:43     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
10:30:43     at require (module.js:380:17)
10:30:43     at Liftoff.handleArguments (/tmp/3791.work/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
10:30:43     at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/tmp/3791.work/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:192:16)
10:30:43     at module.exports (/tmp/3791.work/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
10:30:43     at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/tmp/3791.work/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:185:9)
10:30:43 
10:30:43 npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-34-virtual
10:30:43 npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/n/versions/node/5.5.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/n/versions/node/5.5.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
10:30:43 npm ERR! node v5.5.0
10:30:43 npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
10:30:43 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10:30:43 npm ERR! myproject@1.0.0 build: `gulp && webpack`
10:30:43 npm ERR! Exit status 8
```

part of gulpfile.js:

```
 30 gulp.task( 'sass', () => {
 31   config.sass.targets.forEach( target => {
 32     gulp.src( target.src )
 33       .pipe( sass( config.sass.options ) )
 34       .pipe( gulp.dest( target.dest ) );
 35   });
 36 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow-functions (they are part of es2015) are disabled by default in node 0.10-0.12 and enabled in 5.5

You have got the error in connection with an unsupported syntax of-arrow functions in node 0.10.

To put it simply, when you run `gulp`, then `node gulp` is run. You showed that `which node` gives path to node 0.10, so gulp always runs under it.

**Solution**

`/usr/local/n/versions/node/5.5.0/bin/node $(which gulp)`

Comment: I updated my post and posted all gulp related statements. I have no idea how to specify the node version for gulp.

Comment: @BAE, Gulp should be installed globally and locally at the same time. In our case on our ci-server we have gulp, which is installed globally and we do every building `npm install --dev && gulp`